# Unable to install Ubuntu 15.04 via USB flash drive on a new machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a new machine on a new machine and it’s not working. Here are my system specs:

- **Motherboard:** [GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3P](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4591)
- **CPU:** [AMD FX-6300](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors/desktop/fx)
- **Storage:** [SanDisk SDSSDA-120G-G25](https://www.sandisk.com/home/ssd/ssd-plus)

I have created a USB flash drive installer using [Rufus](https://www.sandisk.com/home/ssd/ssd-plus) for Ubuntu 15.04. The installer starts when the machine boots, and then when I go to the page where it asks me to format the drive, I choose to “Erase disk and install Ubuntu” and clicked install now. It then asks me to confirm that I am erasing all contents and it is going to create partitions for root and swap. I click continue and soon after that screen I get an error saying

> The attempt to mount file system with type ext4 in SCSI5 (0,1,0),
>   partition #1 (sda) at / failed.

I have tried this multiple times and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
The disk is a brand new SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I am reading online, the issue might be connected to the GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3P motherboard. See [GIGABYTE forum thread](http://forum.giga-byte.co.uk/index.php?topic=14802.0), [this other thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223) as well as [this blog post](http://onubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/03/gigabyte-ga-970a-ds3-and-ubuntu.html) which advises:

> After numerous attempts at fixing this, it turns out you simply need
>   to **enable IOMMU support in the UEFI BIOS**. For some reason, IOMMU is
>   disabled by default on this motherboard. Enable it and Ubuntu starts
>   working with the USB as you’d expect.

And some of the posts mention issues with USB 3.0 and bootable USB flash drives working as expected. So if there is a non-USB 3.0 port on that motherboard, I would recommend trying to boot from that bootable USB flash drive in that non-USB 3.0 port.

Now mind you these reports are connected to older versions of Ubuntu, but it’s worth giving these ideas a shot.

Comment: I tried enabling IOMMU. Once I boot sequence starts it throws multiple IO_PAGE_FAULTS and then eventually says `starting version 219`
After which i see the ubuntu loading screen for a long time. It then switched back to the terminal and has a prompt with `(initramfs)`

Comment: It Worked !!!! enabling IOMMU and avoiding the USB 3.0 port works !!
For some reason the installation did not work when my usb device was on the USB 3.0